# How to perfectly align different size text in react native

Tags: react-native

i want to align three text views with different text sizes perfectly to left side, text is now aligned left without any issues but if i use a different text sizes it's gonna look imperfect i want to know is there a way align different sized text perfectly in react native.

[image]

**This is how its looks like when all the fonts are same size**

[image]

**This is how its looks like when using different text sizes**

Comment: In the first image you have the same font-size for all text, if you look for an alignment with different font-size may you should use Views and whit that try to align the text

Comment: It is what i have tried when i set a background color to text it displays it perfectly but characters have this uneven gap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve it by separating your data into columns. For exampel Swivel is col1, List col2 etc . Here is a working (working but no perfect :)) example [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/BwiPQBDCO).

Comment: this seems to work better than before but still not perfect and also splitting the text is not performance friendly.